# iOS - dynamically change height of uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, layout

I want to create suggestions to UISearchBar so I added UITableView and I want to change height of the UITableView by content.

When I get data I call:

```
[self.searchTableView reloadData];
```

and in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` I am trying to resize tableView:

```
    CGRect bounds = [tableView bounds];
    NSLog(@"%f",tableView.contentSize.height);
    [tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x,
                                    bounds.origin.y,
                                    bounds.size.width,
                                    20 * [self.suggestionData count])];

    /*
    CGRect frame = self.searchTableView.frame;;
    frame.size.height = 20 * [self.suggestionData count];
    self.searchTableView.frame = frame;
     */
```

(20 is height of 1 row.) I've tried tableView.contentSize.height too but it didn 't works. Maybe there is need to change something in Storyboard or I when I was trying to find solution I change something wrong. I just get height of tableview same as I set in storyboard. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the height of the UITableView?

Comment: Change height of table. That table is attached to searchBar and is made as suggestions for that searchBar (autocomplete feature).

Comment: Why not just use a UISearchDisplayController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UITableView` extends a `UIScrollView` I suggest you to use the following approach in order to get a table view whose bounds fit its content size.

In the `-init` or `-awakeFromNib` of your special TableView (you can extend the UITableView or create a category) register the observer

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

and then add

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"]) {
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        CGFloat currentHeight = self.contentSize.height;
        if (fabs(currentHeight - frame.size.height) > FLT_EPSILON) {
            frame.size.height = self.contentSize.height;
            self.frame = frame;
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:nil];
    }
}
```

Remember to deregister the observer in the `-dealloc`

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
}
```

Comment: I think I know how this is working but I have a little problem. Self is in my code viewController but it should be tableView is it right? So I should change it to my searchTableView?

Comment: You could make a category of a UITableView since you don't actually need any additional ivar or subclass a tableView adding this autoresizing behaviour. But, if you prefer, you can use the same mechanism inside your controller exploiting the KVO over self.tableView property of your controller. To address more directly your question, yes, you should apply this mechanism on your searchTableView observing changes of its contentSize property

Comment: I must read some articles about this but now I have working solution and it works exactly as I need. Thanks very much :)